# How to map in file.hbm without setting the value?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have scenario like this where I am mapping my class variable without setting it.

```
class residence{
Private Long leadOwnerId;

//with getters and setters for variable
}
```

And I have a table called **lead**. In that I have a column called **owner** in lead table.
My requirement is in **residence.hbm** file i want to map my **leadOwnerId** with **owner** column of lead without setting it.

I am trying like this:

```
 <property name="leadOwnerId" formula="(select owner from lead l where l.id=id)">
 </property>
```

correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Any issues with your mapping so far? I would say, just do not forget to add `insert="false" update="false"` for this property as well... and you are done ;)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I am done with my mapping.

Comment: Great to see that, sir;) good luck with Hibernate ;)